# Reduction in coq when the simpl or cbn tactics are not effective

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am trying to prove this:

```
Fixpoint max(a: nat)(b:nat): nat :=
if a <=? b then b
else a.
Example ex: forall n:nat, n = max n n.
Proof.
intros.
(...)
```

The simpl and cbn tactics do not produce anything.
If I call cbv [max], then I get a redex and I don't know how to continue the proof after that. More precisely, I get:

```
n = (fix max (a b : nat) {struct a} : nat := if a <=? b then b else a) n n
```

How to get rid of this redex `(fix max ....) n n` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `Fixpoint` even though the function is not recursive, and that is where `fix` comes from. Use `Definition` instead.

A `fix` only reduces when the structurally decreasing argument (here `n`, the first one) starts with a constructor. So if your function were really meant to be recursive, you could use `destruct n.`.